# Node.js / Express.js Removing user from request, removes it from database

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

Here is the code:

```
exports.delete = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.user);
  req.user.remove(function (err) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(req.user);
    }
  })
};
```

Of course this function is callback of `delete` method, what I don't understand is that, why removing `req.user` also deletes the specific user from MongoDB, as it is just a request.

Edit:

I have another callback(GET) which is executed on the same route:

```
exports.userByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
  User.findOne({
    _id: id
  }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

User is MongoDB model.

Comment: is `req.user` your mongoDb model?

Comment: If you just want to remove user property from request, just use `delete req.user`

Comment: That is the case, req.user is not mongoDb model in any way, it is just callback request.

Comment: Okay. then do you happen to have some route defined where you are setting req.user to mongoDb model? Becuase, `req.user.remove` happens to be a function that works as mongoDb's `Model.remove`. Chances are high this is a mongoDb model. Please take a look at all the routes.

Comment: @Maverick please check edited question.

Comment: Can you please post route's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you do your `req.user = user` you're setting the value of `req.user` to the instance of your mongodb model.

So, calling `req.user.remove` is in fact calling your mongodb model `remove` function.

Change your delete function to:

```
exports.delete = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.user);
  delete req.user
  //etc...
};
```

`delete req.user` will remove the user object from your request object

Comment: This answer is correct as long as removing `user` property from `req` is concerned. However, saying that setting `req.user=user` sets value of `req.user` to instance of mongoDb model is incorrect. :) Becuase `user` parameter in the callback will be the data we just fetched, not the model. The mongoDb model, in this case is `User` not `user` (capital U) :)

Comment: `Instances of these models represent documents` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: Thanks :) I misinterpreted.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, I just want to understand what is happening here, as I see when the first GET route is executed, it assigns MongoDB user model to req.user and after that it is passed to delete method and finally removed, that is why it is erased from DB too.